# How to compare timestamp with current time in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sql query in oracle.
I want to select records which has field "c_time"  (format by timestamp) older than current time 5 minutes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the typical way would be:

```
where c_time < current_timestamp - interval '5' minute
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is

```
where c_time < systimestamp - (5/(24*60))
```

24*60 is used to convert the value in minutes.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

We can also try using the `NUMSTODSINTERVAL()` function here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE c_time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - NUMTODSINTERVAL(5, 'MINUTE');
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
where EXTRACT(year FROM c_time)=EXTRACT(year FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and 
    EXTRACT(month FROM c_time)=EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    EXTRACT(day FROM c_time)=EXTRACT(day FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    EXTRACT(hour FROM c_time) =EXTRACT(hour FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    EXTRACT(minute FROM c_time)-5>EXTRACT(minute FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```